# U2 Basic Developer Toolkit

Tags: ide, backwards-compatibility, unidata, u2, multivalue-database

Does anyone here run the Basic Developer Toolkit with UniData 7.1?

Even though the IDE was released with UniData 7.2, I was given the impression that it works fine with 7.1. However, when opening up "Database Files" in an account, every single DIR type file gives a loading error dialog and doesn't register any records in them.

Are changes needed the the UniData server before the IDE works with 7.1, or is something else afoot here. As far as I know it just uses UniObjects for Java to talk to the UniData RPC daemon, so there shouldn't be any issues with communications.

Working with a decent IDE would be nice...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run BDT on older releases and we developed a Tech Note to explain how to install what you need. This doc was released with U2 Technical Resource Kit for 2009-10 if you got a copy of that at U2U. If not and you are on support you can access the doc online at: https://u2tc.rocketsoftware.com/documentation/display.asp?id=1392476.

Answer (score 1):

BDT was released for Unidata 7.2.  There is another Eclipse IDE for U2 that works for Unidata 6.0 and above called XLr8Editor for U2logic.  You can get a trial for free just follow the download instructions at www.u2logic.com/downloads.html.

Regards,
Doug

Comment: Thanks Doug, I just want to know if anyone on 7.1 currently uses it since I was told at U2U that it should work fine, however it appears that this is not so. I might download the trial from home to check it out. A proper IDE would be nice for a change :)